# IE7 Wierd spacing issue

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Hi all and good morning!

The issue I'm having today is with IE7's rendering (shock, horror) of my work in progress website. Below is some code that is intended to create a page wide `<div>` that has an image on the left hand side (an arrow) and then 2 lines of text to the right of the image, then a progress bar holder `<div>` with another `<div>` inside that will be widened and narrowed to fill the progress bar.

```
<div class="courseItem">
            <img src="images/courses-arrow.jpg" width="41" height="41" alt="->" />
            <p><span class="title">Intermediate Microsoft Excel 2010</span><br />
            <strong>Last accessed:</strong> 21st September 2011</p>
            <div class="courseProgress">
                <div class="progressContainer">
                    <div class="progressFill" style="width: 60px">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>50%</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </div>
```

Now, what's the problem you ask? Well the issue is that for some reason, and this has really stumped me, the first of these bar divs (there are 4 in total, all exactly the same as the code above, no changes what so ever) has a massive white space between itself and its border which forces the other 3 bars below to be pushed away.

Here's the css;

```
.courseItem {
margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b0dff7;}

.courseItem img {
float: left;
margin: 0px 20px 15px 0px;}

.courseItem p {
font-size: 11px;
color: #999999;
margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0;
float: left;}

.courseItem p span.title {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
color: #00154d}

.courseItem .courseProgress {
float: right;}

 .courseItem .courseProgress p {
width: 50px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #52b9ed;
margin: 7px 0px 0px 10px;}

 .courseItem .courseProgress .progressContainer {
margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0;
width: 120px;
height: 12px;
background: url(../images/courses-empytprogress.jpg) no-repeat;
float: left;}

.courseItem .courseProgress .progressContainer .progressFill {
margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
height: 10px;
max-width: 120px;
background: url(../images/courses-fillprogress.jpg) repeat-x;
float: left;}
```

This is the visual representation

http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/10/29204251178-orig.jpg

Thanks in advance.

(Sorry for long windedness, just trying to paint a picture)

Comment: You should enclose the relevant CSS code in your question.

Comment: My bad, I just didnt want to make this a HUGE ass question.

Comment: could you explain it more clear ? are you saying, there is huge space for the beginners microsoftword from the top and bottom of the border ? how exactly you want your output to be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `float:left` property of `.div p`, and add `display:inline-block;`. Then, define the `clear:both` CSS property for the `.clearBoth` class.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jqhe8/**

Fixed CSS:

```
.courseItem p {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999999;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block; /*Removed float, added display*/
}
.clearBoth { /*Define clear:both!!!*/
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I had actually defined .clearBoth in another part of the stylesheet my bad. Your display-inline solved the issue on the left but now the right hand side progress bars are on the bottom of the div (as if the display-inlined <p></p> has forced it down a line)

Comment: `display:inline` causes an element to be `inline`. You should have a look at the styles of your progress bar in order to find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you didn't clear it's `parent div` & you `.clear` `class` is not working so; first `clear` the `parent div` because the `child div's` have `float` in it. Write like this

```
.courseItem {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B0DFF7;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I had actually defined .clearBoth in another part of the stylesheet my bad.

Comment: it's better to clear a div with css not with extra markup But if you  want in the markup then write margin:0, padding:0 & height:0 in the .clearBoth css